# Obtain OAuth2 token using android AccountManager?

Tags: java, android, google-api, oauth-2.0, accountmanager

Is it possible to obtain a `OAuth2` token to use with Google APIs, using the android `AccountManager`?  The only other way I know of would be to have a `webView` and make the user log in to obtain the `OAuth2` token, but it would seem to be a lot of work for that many people would want to do, so if I could just obtain it using `AccountManager` that would be much better. Is there any functionality like this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`AccountManager` is not for generating tokens at all - its only for storing credentials related to an `Account`. These classes are not specific to Google server accounts - you can use them for any type of account. For example, I use them to store OAuth2 tokens for Facebook, Twitter, etc.

You will need to use the Google APIs to generate an OAuth2 token, which you store in an `Account` using the `AccountManager`. You need to use the Google APIs, because part of the OAuth2 token generation occurs on the server itself - Google will store a record of the tokens it has given out, and the server accounts that they are related to. If you didn't call the Google APIs to generate the token, Google wouldn't know how to match the token to a Google server account.

Your approach of using a `WebView` to obtain the OAuth2 token is the correct way to do this.

Once you have the OAuth2 token stored for the `Account`, you just retrieve it from the `AccountManager` whenever you want to use it to make a query. So, you only need to generate the OAuth2 token once (unless it expires), and then you keep using it over and over again.

Comment: Downvoter - I'd love to know your reason for the downvote, especially considering I know this to be true because I use it in a number of my own Android apps. Care to enlighten me?

Comment: I didn't downvote you, but something along the lines of 'manager.getAuthToken(account, "Manage your tasks", ...)' should work without first calling the Google APIs.  Each API has a different string that should work for that second parameter.